# Save api json to database using laravel

Tags: json, api, laravel

Is it possible to get data from an api url and save it directly to database when working with laravel? the data i get from the url is of the format {"name":"100KVA SUKAM Generator","level":"5.965"}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create table with `json` type field (or `text`) and keep data there:

```
$table->json('data_from_api');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#writing-migrations

If you want to persist data as usual data, you can use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#mass-assignment). First, convert JSON to an array with `[json_decode][1]` and save data like that:

```
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true)
Model::create($data);
```

Don't forget to add all columns to a `$fillable` property of a model.

Comment: thanks, i am a little bit confused on how to go about taking the information from the page. i know i have to use onload function to call the information to the view from the api, also do i use a post method and if correct how do i accomplish this. i really appreciate your help @alexey-mezenin